# Would dual saberstaffs offer a greater advantage to other lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars, weapon, the-clone-wars

General [Krell](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Pong_Krell) demonstrates in *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* that the use of two saberstaffs is plausible:

[image: Besalisk Jedi Pong Krell wielded two double-bladed sabers]

However, is it advantageous in battle, as opposed to dual lightsabers or a single saberstaff?

Comment: That's the most ridiculous thing I've ever seen. And I've seen Jar Jar Binks.

Comment: Man, he's got four arms. Why doesn't he just use 4 double-bladed lightsabers

Comment: @SSumner - 'cause then he'd be copycatting Grevious :)

Comment: @DVK Not even Grievous tried that. He was at least sane enough to use four single blades. :P

Comment: I want to know why he isn't holding 2 more of those things with his free hands... I mean if you go ridiculous... go all the way.

Comment: 1 light saber can behead an infinite number of Sith!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As discussed in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12414/4678), dual lightsabers limit your balance and movement. Additionally, your mind must focus on more objects, something even a force-user will find more difficult than using a single lightsaber. Additionally, when you swing a double-bladed lightsaber, you have to be constantly aware of where the other blade is to avoid cutting your own limbs. This is going to limit the range of motion of your attacks and defenses. While it may look cool, using dual dual-bladed lightsabers is not very practical.

Comment: "not very practical" is an understatement. There's no chance he doesn't kill or seriously hurt himself with those. No matter how talented a Jedi he might be.

Comment: I'm super glad I never watched this series now.

Comment: Yeah, if he doesn't kill himself he's go no chance of protecting himself because he can't cover a huge area of his body for defense

Comment: You statements are driven by species-prejudice. For all you know, other alien species may have a completely different and/or superior sense of proprioception, the mental awareness of their bodies physical position, balance and coordination. Being an alien lifeform, may give them a superior ability at using a technology that may or may not be as effectively used as HUMANS can. For them, the ability to use double-lightsabers may simply be GREATER than ours.

Comment: Except for species that have super-long arms, it doesn't matter their proprioception, they'll still cut themselves when moving the lightsabers in many ways. A humanoid (or someone like General Krell) is not built right to use one. Oh, and in Star Wars it's called specieism

Comment: With the length of those blades, on front AND back, there's no freaking way something with arms that length could wield those effectively. Sword art is the same regardless of what kind of mental/physical awareness the creature wielding them has. You simply could not wield that effectively. The fulcrum points are too far outside of the "I'm cutting my arm off" range.

Comment: it seems practical to me, but then I'm no jedi or swordsman. Note in the [youtube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPvNkIPFdI8), that he angles his body side on keeping 1 arm behind and 1 in front.

Answer (score 2):

This is far from practical. The reason that General Krell was able to wield dual saberstaves was because he had four arms. It requires two arms to wield a saberstaff effectively, watch the episode where the clones arrested him. So unless you have two bonus arms . . .
Also, for those arguing even Krells ability to wield them, this is a fictional universe, and he was a Jedi. Force-sensitives can do a lot most normal people can't.

Comment: Except that, as in the above picture, he generally held and used each lightsaber in one hand and left the other hands free.

Answer (score 0):

this is not exactly true. I have been practicing with the staff, and am on my way to being able to wield two. it is possible, it would just take lots of training and practice. I have already found a dual staff spin that is effective.