# How would using two wands work?

Tags: harry-potter

The answer to this question should really focus on the either proving or disproving the points below and stating a summary or conclusion to your answer which states how you think the evidence more strongly aligns.

**The first point would have to be whether it would work at all.**

How would you cast a spell from two wands? Would you use them in separate hands or together?
You do not need to answer these smaller points in your answer they are just my own thoughts.

**The second point would have to be whether it would actually affect the power of the spell**

As we all know (or at least I hope you do) the wand is used to focus magical energy so really would we not end up with a larger and less focussed point for magical energy?

**Would you actually be able to cast one spell that went to two separate targets?**

This would only be apt for using two wands in separate hands but the coordination required for this would be incredible and possibly take years to learn to do effectively at least.

End of points. Now for some **discussion**.

Clearly you would need two wands that would be aligned to you, thus the elder wand rears it's ugly head again! As Dumbledore would have had 2 wands at one point, Harry also did after repairing his own with the elder wand but that wasn't his style. Dumbledore out of all wizards could have learnt to use two wands although knowledge and skill was more to his liking that pure power.(The hallows excluded) I am going to imagine that I will gain an answer that will just state no wizard in the books was seen to do this so it isn't something that will happen.

**How would using two wands work?**

Comment: Since my VTC is binding, I am open to being convinced that ythis needs to stay open and isn't really a dupe.

Comment: Seems very dupe like in the basics, I did search but with incorrect terminology it seems, I would prefer more of a detailed answer than what the answer to the other question has. However I think that we have no sources for how or any of the other more detailed aspects anyway. @DVK

Comment: In my answer on a duplicate question, most of these are answered (yes it works, yes, the power is greater). There's no canon discussion ever of sending a spell at 2 separate targets with 2 separate wands, John Woo style)

Comment: "Clearly you would need two wands that would be aligned to you" - again , the quote in that answer proves you wrong. Harry was holding 3 random wands, only one of which clearly had his alliegence and none were "aligned" in a sense of choosing him

Comment: @DVK I think either I explained wrongly or was misinterpreted wrongly, I do mean the user would need the allegiance of wands. Although good point as I don't think harry actually had the allegiance of all 3 in that scene did he? But yes feel free to leave it closed, It is a partial dupe and the remainder of the question can either not be explained or is not feature in canon or both.

Comment: I added a comment to that answer to explain the rest (and my personal speculation that if it WAS possible, JKR may have mentioned it in several multiple-to-one duels during Battle of Hogwarts)

Comment: @DVK This may answer you as to why they wouldn't so willingly use extra wands. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/12414/22709 This was also my inspiration for the question but ohwell, thanks for the extra info and etc. Fun Fact, this is the second of 2 questions i've posted that you have found a duplicate of with different wording in the title :D

Answer (score 3):

In the battle of Malfoy Manor in Deathly Hallows, Harry takes three wands from Malfoy and holds them all together in one hand. He then casts a spell on someone with all three wands, which seems to amplify the power of the spell.

So, short answer: You can definitely use multiple wands in one hand, but only on one target.

Comment: It was Fenrir Greyback.