# Why don't wizards use more than one wand like when Harry uses three?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore

In the seventh book, when Harry is escaping from Malfoy Mansion he grabs three wands from Draco Malfoy and uses a spell against the snatcher Scabior. The effects are described as more powerful than a single wand spell.

What is the downside to this "strategy", for it to not be commonly used among wizards as one can seemingly create more powerful spells?

Comment: @Rand al'Thor The duplicate chain on this is something fierce, and going to back to the questions that are not closed, they don't seem to answer this. I think something along on the chain needs to be reopened but I'm not sure what...

Comment: @Skooba Perhaps [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/146200/31394) could be reopened? The two later ones are pretty clear dupes of it, but the two earlier ones, even taken together, don't seem to resolve it properly.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes, that one should not be a duplicate of the two it is closed based on, but the two questions closed based on it are indeed duplicates.