# Why are Jedi obsessed with lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, weapon, lightsaber

In the movie *A New Hope* we see Obi-Wan training Luke to use the lightsaber of his father.

> HAN: Hokey religions and ancient weapons are no match for a good blaster at your side, kid.

Blasters are as good as guns and their velocities surely help in tearing off enemies. With the help of force they are surely good weapons.

Can’t Jedi interact with the force with help of blasters?

<sub>Please consider using spoiler tags in your answer as I have only watched Episode IV</sub>

Comment: “Blasters are as good as guns” — *[citation needed]*. Stormtroopers have blasters, Jedi have lightsabers, and I know who tends to do better in fights.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The Jedi were massacred by the Clone troopers with blasters. And they replaced Jedi as the backbone of the Republic's army. Just sayin' that one-on-one lightsabers win bu a million-on-one the blasters are pretty effective.

Comment: dup of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/107468/why-do-jedi-use-lightsabers?rq=1  ?

Comment: @Lan Yeah, but A-million-on-a-million I would give put my money on the lightsaber wielders.

Comment: Who wouldn't want a lightsabre?

Answer (score 6):

The clue is in Obi-Wan's dialogue as he hands Luke the lightsaber. From the [Episode IV script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html):

> OBI-WAN: Your father's lightsaber. This is the weapon of a Jedi Knight. Not as clumsy or as random as a blaster. An elegant weapon for a more civilized time.

So Obi-Wan believes lightsabers are "elegant", as opposed to "clumsy." He isn't just looking for an efficient means of killing people; he wants a weapon which reflects his philosophy and ideals. Anyone can fire a blaster, but effectively using a lightsaber requires the skill and discipline of a Jedi.

Comment: Doesn't _really_ answer the question. "Why are Jedi obsessed with lightsabers?" "Because they think they are elegant." "Why do they think they are elegant?" "Because they are obsessed with lightsabers."

Comment: @Lan No, more like "Why do they think they are elegant?" "Because they require skill and discipline to use, thereby reflecting the basic philosophy of a Jedi."