# Why didn't Anakin keep Count Dooku's lightsaber?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith

I got this question after watching some cutscenes from *Lego Star Wars: The Skywalkers Saga*

Anakin just killed Dooku, and Grievous walked in, (unlike the movie) and the duo of Kenobi & Skywalker assume a fighting pose, ***with Anakin holding Dooku's saber.***

Why didn't this happen in the original movie? Not the Grievous part but Anakin keeping the lightsaber to fight Grievous later, I mean.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure the Jedi frown on taking trophies.

Comment: @Nu'Daq - Jedi certainly aren't above using impromptu weapons. though. Obi-Wan uses a blaster, for example.

Answer (score 4):

Anakin dropped it in shock at the enormity of his actions.

> Now he stood over a headless corpse that he couldn’t bear to see but
> he couldn’t make himself look away, and **he knew it hadn’t been a dream
> at all, that he’d really done this, the blades were still in his hands
> and the ocean of wrong he’d dived into had closed over his head.**
>
> And he was drowning.
>
> **The dead man’s lightsaber tumbled from his loosening fingers.** “I-I
> couldn’t stop myself…”
>
> And before the words left his lips he heard how hollow and obvious was
> the lie.
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Official Novelisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_%E2%80%93_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup></sub>

History doesn't record why he didn't pick it up, but I would assume he simply wasn't inclined to do so, noting that he's mainly [trained to use one lightsaber, not two](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12398/why-do-jedi-use-one-lightsaber-in-combat). Having a second one is dead weight.